# Bootstrap cards not maintaing row column format

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have the following template:

```
<center>
      <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'movie:recommend'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input style="font-color:#000000;color: #008000" type="Submit" value="Recommend">
  </center>
  <br></br>
  <div class ="container">
            <div class="row">
        {% for movie in movies %}


        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card h-12">
        <div class="card-deck">

            <div class="card text-center" style="width:20rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{movie.img_url}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{movie.title}}</h5>
            <a href="{% url 'movie:explore' movie.id %}" class="btn btn-dark">Explore</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <br></br>
 </div>


   {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The cards should have been displayed in the following format:

```
card1  card2  card3  card4
card5  card6  card7  card8
.
.
it goes on like this
```

However the layout isn't maintained and cards don't follow this. My display page has no cards on position card5, card6, card7 and then similarly on card13 and card14. For some sequence of rows, the format is maintained but then it again gets distored at random rows.

How to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `card` nested inside `card`?

Comment: Inspect in the browser if the width and height of each card are maintained or they get different values because of its own content. Also try to remove the br br tags.

Answer (score 0):

checkout your movies array it might hav some Empty value

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddel Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h8pncfeg/1/)

you can try to create a `<div class="row">` and inside it put as much cards as you want with this classes `class="col-6 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 pb-3"` which will make it responsive....

This is a the basic responsive `Card` structure

```html
<div class="col-6 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 pb-3">
  <div class="card">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/blogclan-2/images/b/b9/Random-image-15.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160706220047" alt="Car">
     <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">Price</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```